# Getting a grid to overlap other grids in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, grid

I'm in the process of writing a custom drop down button in silverlight. While I haven't reached that point yet I'm worried about how the drop down will hover over other controls.

Is there a way I can make a grid which overlaps other controls so that I can populate the grid with controls and stuff for the drop down?

Comment: sounds like you just need to style a ComboBox to look like a drop down button?

Comment: so what's stopping you now? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'd look into the Popup control.  That's the most common way I've seen that done.  A good place to start would be to look at the Themes (you can see the controls used by the templates) in the Silverlight Toolkit as well as the controls implemented there: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/